# Apache url rewrite problem

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

requests  ----->  should be written to new url

/institute/dps   ----->  /institute.php?slug=dps
/institute/abc   ----->  /institute.php?slug=abc
/institute/123   ----->  /institute.php?slug=123

I am using following rule in .htaccess
RewriteRule ^institute/(.*)$ /institute.php?slug=$1

However, it's not working.  the page insitute.php get's execution, but the query string always comes empty.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you saying the redirect isn't working, or that it's not changing the URL in the address bar? Where is your .htaccess file located?

Comment: are there any other rules in your .htaccess that might be conflicting?

Answer (score 1):

That should work... If you try

```
RewriteRule ^institute/(.*)$ /institute.php?slug=$1 [R]
```

it should redirect formally, and you'll see the new URI

If you don't have the [R] in there it will issue the correct request, but you won't see  `?slug=` in the query string, but `$_REQUEST['slug']` will be set.

Comment: [if you don't use [R] the redirect won't be visible, but will still be actioned]

Answer (score 0):

Have you turned on Rewriting in your .htaccess file? (before your RewriteRule)

```
RewriteEngine On
```

If so - does your apache configuration allow you to use .htaccess file? (look for the line)

```
AllowOverride None
```

inside you httpd.conf
it SHOULD be

```
AllowOverride All
```

Finally make sure the url rewriting module is turned on in httpd.conf (it might be commented out)

LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so